Why does the loan company require I have $250;in my account so they can deposit the loan?
I got approved for a loan but the company is requesting that I have $250 in my cashapp acct so the loan can be deposited in to the account. Is that normal or is it a scam?

it's a scam. No legitimate loan company requires you to do this sort of thing. Run away

Welcome, Amber! In general your questions will get more answers if you provide additional details: what country this is taking place in, what sort of loan you're dealing with, how you found the lender, etc. But in this case you've already listed enough red flags to make a scam highly likely, so it's best take precautions with any information you've already shared with the company and stop communicating with them.

It's a scam.
Cashapp, Venmo, PayPal, and other similar services are not where funds from a loan will be disbursed to.
Generally speaking, lenders will only give you the money in one of three ways:

Wired to a deposit account with a reputable bank or brokerage.
Cashier's Check written to the payee of your choice (or to you).
As a form of revolving line of credit, for which you are provided a credential (credit card or checkbook for stuff like HELOCs).

Anyone telling you to load up your CashApp believes they have, or are about to have, your credentials so as to be able to drain that account.
In addition to not complying, you should immediately change your CashApp password, and change your password anywhere you use the same password (which you shouldn't be doing, but is still very common).
The only meaningful exception wherein you could possibly encounter a deposit minimum before the lender will disburse funds, is if the account you are being asked to fund is with the lender themselves.  Banks may require you open a deposit account (into which they will disburse the loan funds) with them, and that process may involve a minimum balance to open and/or establish - but again, this is not "Load up your CashApp" this is a bank saying "We'll give you this loan if you're a customer of ours, so you should use $250 to open a savings account with us."
Typically, however, the bank will simply use the loan proceeds to open the deposit account in this case, rather than make you go through the trouble. So even in this instance, you should probably do business with someone else anyway.
